# Shell theorem of an oblate spheroid.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Isaac Newton famously proved [the shell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) and stated that:

"A spherically symmetric body affects external objects gravitationally as though all of its mass were concentrated at a point at its center.

I would like help to come up with a similar theorem for an oblate spheroid. I have a hunch (or a hope) that the oblate shell equation will be something like $$F = \frac{G M m}{2} \left( \frac 1 {R_1^2} + \frac{1}{R_2^2} \right)$$

where $R_1$ and $R_2$ are the distances of the test object of mass m from the two foci $F_1$ and $F_2$ of the elliptical cross section of the oblate spheroid as in the diagram below:

[image]

I can just about follow the proof in Wikipedia for the spherical case, but I don't think my calculus is good enough to extend this to the oblate spheroid case. Is there a know solution or has it even been attempted?

Going by the diagram I guess a similar method can be used as is used for the spherical case, integrating $\theta$ from $\theta = 0$ to $\theta = \pi$, but using implicit differentiation and using using $S$ as the integration variable instead of $\theta$.

There is the additional difficulty that in this case $R$ varies with $\theta$ or $S$. From the [Wikipedia page on the ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse), I have gathered from the standard parametric presentation of the ellipse that $$R = \sqrt{(a \ cos \theta)^2 + (b \ cos \theta)^2 } $$ where a is the usual semi-major axis and b is the semi-minor axis. After that, I am out of my depth. Ideally, although it might be asking too much, I would like the more general case for m at any location outside or on the oblate spheroid surface.

Answer (score 0):

Shell method fails in spheroids and triaxial ellipsoid because of symmetry breaking.

Ellipsoidal coordinates should be used instead.

Please refer to the following links:

- Oblate spheroid in **Science World** [*here*](https://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/OblateSpheroidGravitationalPotential.html).
- Prolate spheroid in **Science World** [*here*](https://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/ProlateSpheroidGravitationalPotential.html).
- Please refer to my older post for triaxial ellipsoid [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2273404/the-gravity-potential-of-an-ellipsoid/2273419#2273419).